# No applicable name scope exists to resolve the name 'ellipse'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard

I am trying out WPF and have a problem while creating animations for my "Othello Buttons".

So, I made a new Class `Token : Button` with some Properties.  And I also added a `RessourceDictionary` with a `StoryBoard`. Now I want to start this in a Switch Case. When I do this, I get the following error:

> No applicable name scope exists to resolve the name 'ellipse'.

```
 <!-- TOKEN TEMPLATE -->
<Style x:Key="Token" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="ToWhite">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="Black"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black"/>
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="White"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="ToBlack">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="ToEnabled">
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black"/>
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="White"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0.19"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
```

Here is My Token Class

```
public class Token : Button
{
    Storyboard sbToWhite = new Storyboard();
    Storyboard sbToBlack = new Storyboard();
    Storyboard sbToEnabled = new Storyboard();

    public Token()
    {
        BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gainsboro);

        sbToBlack = (Storyboard)TryFindResource("ToBlack");
        sbToEnabled = (Storyboard)TryFindResource("ToEnabled");;
    }

    private GameState.TokenState _status;

    public Point Point { get; set; }

    public GameState.TokenState Status { get { return _status; } 
    set
    {
        _status = value;
        switch (value)
        {
            case GameState.TokenState.NONE:
                IsSet = false;
                break;
            case GameState.TokenState.WHITE:
                ((Storyboard)TryFindResource("ToWhite")).Begin();
                IsSet = true;
                break;
            case GameState.TokenState.BLACK:
                sbToBlack.Begin();
                IsSet = true;
                break;
            case GameState.TokenState.ENABLED:
                sbToEnabled.Begin();
                IsSet = false;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a target to `Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse"`?

Comment: are you sure that there is an element in storyboard scope with name "ellipse"?

Comment: Your animation is animating in the scope of your control instead of the scope of your template. This is a classic case for `VisualStateManager`. You set the state of the control in code and define the animations for each state via XAML.